How can I claim Ukrainian citizenship by descent?
I am enquiring how we can get dual nationality so we can become recognised as Ukrainian.  My mum, whilst born in UK was born from 2 Ukrainian nationals but both were denied to return following WW2.  Most documents such as passport of my grandfather were surrendered.  I believe we only possess my Ukrainian grandparents birth certificates.
As the granddaughter of my Ukrainian descendants I am proud of my heritage and want to know how or if I can obtain dual citizenship / nationality.
My children are too interested in adopting this heritage.  My eldest son particularly would like to know if he can obtain this to decide whether or not he could swim internationally to represent UK or Ukraine.
Do you know if there is a way dual nationality/citizenship can be claimed and what the process is please to receive it what with so little documents available due to having to hand them to Germany when being exiled to UK?

You are the descendant of your Ukrainian ancestors.  Descendants: children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc.  Ancestors: grandparents, great-grandparents, etc.

Obtaining citizenship by descent appears to be possible, however it looks like you might have to renounce other citizenship(s). See also military service
